# Isn't this a dot product?

Tags: notation, derivatives, vector-fields

The problem (Arfken, chapter 3, problem 3.10.26) begins with this and asks to verify it in Cartesian coordinates and in spherical coordinates.

$$\mathbf{A} \cdot  \mathbf{\nabla}\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{A}$$

What troubles me is the dot relation, how this yields a vector not a scalar?

Comment: This is a question about mathematics, not physics.

Comment: Arfken is usually described as a 'mathematical methods' book, because it is about mathematical tools of interest to physicist, not about physics *per se*.

Comment: OK I guess $\mathbf{r}$ means position vector $\vec{r}$... and yes this is not physics at all...

Comment: Guys, but this identity shows up in fluid mechanics all of the time. In fact, a special case of it shows up in the Euler equation, namely the term: $\mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla \mathbf{u}$. In fact, in almost every fluid dynamics course, the first problem set always has a question involving proving an identity related to this. So, I would say from this perspective, it is very much a physics question as well! :)

Comment: ohh, anyway I figured it out! The only way for this to make sense is just if computed (A . del) first then applied that to the vector r. This way it is a dot product between the vector A and the del operator getting a scalar which is then applied to r getting us a vector as indicated. So, I guess it was all about the notation!

Answer (score 5):

It would be easier to see how things going around with matrix notations, let the arbitrary vector $\mathbf{A} $ has components $a,b,c$:
$$\mathbf{A} \cdot  \mathbf{\nabla}\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{A} \implies\begin{bmatrix} 
a&b&c  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
\partial_x \\
\partial_y \\
\partial_z  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
x \\
y \\
z  
\end{bmatrix}
$$
here it is obvious that the operator $\nabla$can't act on $\mathbf{r}$ directly.
$$=(a\partial_x+b\partial_y+c\partial_z)\begin{bmatrix} 
x \\
y \\
z  
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix} 
(a\partial_x+b\partial_y+c\partial_z)x \\
(a\partial_x+b\partial_y+c\partial_z)y \\
(a\partial_x+b\partial_y+c\partial_z)z  
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix} 
a \\
b \\
c  
\end{bmatrix}$$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Great answer. But, another way to see this, is that it may be easier to write the equation as: $(\mathbf{A} \cdot \nabla) r = A$

Answer (score 2):

In $d$ dimensions we have
$$
\mathbf{A} \cdot  \mathbf{\nabla}\mathbf{r} 
= (\mathbf{A} \cdot  \mathbf{\nabla})\mathbf{r} 
= (\sum_{k=1}^{d} A_k \partial_k)\mathbf{r} 
= \sum_{k=1}^{d} A_k (\partial_k \mathbf{r} )
= \sum_{k=1}^{d} A_k \mathbf{e}_k
= \mathbf{A},
$$
where $\mathbf{e}_k$ is the unit vector in the $x_k$ direction.